# Numpy doesn't count pixels in image correctly

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to count black and white pixels in an image with Numpy and OpenCV. However, the final count doesn't match the real value. By using the following image (4x4):

[image]

In the following code:

```
# importing libraries
import cv2
import numpy as np
from math import *

path = "pictures/test.png"

# reading the image data from desired directory
img = cv2.imread(path)
cv2.imshow('Image', img)

height, width, color = img.shape

# counting the number of pixels
number_of_white_pix = np.sum(img == 255)
number_of_black_pix = np.sum(img == 0)


def phase():
    white = number_of_white_pix
    black = number_of_black_pix
    phaseper = white/(white+black)
    print(white)
    print(black)
    return phaseper

print(phase())
```

I get the following output:

```
9
36
0.2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Which means it counted 9 white pixels and 36 black pixels, which is clearly wrong, as it can be seen from the image that the correct number is 3 white and 13 pixels (for a total of 4x4 = 16 pixels). Since the code is not giving any errors and doesn't seem to be wrong, I do not know what is going on.

Comment: What is `img.shape`? Is it really a 4x4 image?

Comment: "The shape of an image is accessed by img.shape. It returns a tuple of the number of rows, columns, and channels (if the image is color)". And yes, it is a 4x4 image.

Comment: No, I mean what is the value of `img.shape`?

Comment: When I insert "print(img.shape)" in the code it prints (4, 4, 3)

Comment: For what it's worth the image you attached is 160x160 not actually 4x4.

Comment: So then you have 3x3=9 array elements with a value of 255. You might want to convert the image to grayscale, for example by extracting a single channel.

Comment: The attached image appears to be 160x160 because I inserted a  "b" before ".png" in the image URL to make the image bigger in stack overflow. If you remove it, it shows the true 4x4 image

Comment: Chris, could you please elaborate on how could I do such convertion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dumping the data of the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzJlO.png) using `print(img)` gives

```
[[[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  1   1   1]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
```

This agrees with the results of your code: we have 9 `255`s and 36 `0`s. As you can see one of the pixels is not quite black, but a very dark gray.

The reason each value appears three times is because it is encoded as [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rgb). If you only care about handling grayscale images, you can tell `opencv` to load the image as grayscale instead:

```
img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
"""
print(img) now gives
[[  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [255 255 255   0]
 [  1   0   0   0]]
"""
```